# Getting error when putting complicated arguments in min function? Why?(Eclipse C++)

Tags: c++, eclipse, templates, arguments, min

I need your help

```
if(s[i]==t)
{
    //I get error for this
    //aSP[pos] = min( (dfs(i)+pow(i-pos,2)) , aSP[pos] );

    //Then I replace the above code with the following codes, and then it worked
    int a = (dfs(i)+pow(i-pos,2));
    int b = aSP[pos];            
    aSP[pos] = min(a,b);
}
```

But they are the **same** right? Why am I getting error from Eclipse?
It says

> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Invalid arguments '
>   Candidates are:
>   const #0 & min(const #0 &, const #0 &)
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type no matching function for call
>   to 'min(__gnu_cxx::__promote_2::__type,
>   int&)'    ColorfulRoad.h  /colorfulroad-c++   line 53 C/C++ Problem

and some other information as well, like conflicting type for parameters, template argument deduction/substitution failed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message means that in this function call

```
aSP[pos] = min( (dfs(i)+pow(i-pos,2)) , aSP[pos] );
```

the first and the second arguments have different types. So the compiler can not deduce the type of the template parameter.

You could help the compiler specifying explicitly the template argument. For example

```
aSP[pos] = min<int>( (dfs(i)+pow(i-pos,2)) , aSP[pos] );
```

In the second call of the function the both arguments have type int. So the template parameter is deduced to int.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to understand if you have GCC error instead:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'min(double, int)'
     std::min(2.0, 3);
                    ^
```

Just cast first argument to int.